# Fastest way to grab a arbitrary number of UserIDs from my Parse database

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, swift, parse-platform

My application is going to have to grab the UserIDs of a arbitrary number of users very often (let's say that the number of random UserIDs being grabbed is between 1 and 100).

Every solution I can think of would involve `count` which is pretty expensive and slow from my (limited) understanding.

I won't need the entire row returned, just the UserID (the primary key in this case). What approach would be the fastest and most scale-able? Is there a  way I can take advantage of just querying the index as the only thing I will actually need is the primary key?

Assume the table is called Users and the primary key of course is UserId. The amount of users in the table can be in the millions.

Comment: Far as I know the max objects you can grab is 100. Not sure you'll be able to query for millions of IDs.

Comment: @remus I believe you can set the return limit to 1000 which would be fine for my uses. Is their an actual limit for doing a find? If so is their any scale-able way of getting around it?

Comment: I have never used Parse, so this may not be an answer to your question, but if your userIDs are sequential integer values, then the most efficient way to get the total number of users in a database would be to keep a metadata table that maintained the number of users who are currently registered. Then just query for that number when you need to get a random userID.

Comment: Sorry, yeah I meant 1000 - missed a 0  As far as I know, PFQuery could get you a smaller subset of data (just the id) but I don't think it scales more than that.

Comment: @miken.mkndev that's a pretty good solution - provided that no one deletes an account anyway (or OP properly anticipates gaps in the array of results)

Comment: @miken.mkndev they can be sequential integers for sure. I was just thinking that I could use something like that as well. Hopefully someone will know the limitation of parse better than me, and point me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, good point. Generally speaking I try to not allow user's to actually delete an account. When they want to delete I just de-activate the user account, and then run a background process that clears out content generated by de-activated users once a day. This way the content they created is truly deleted, but their account still exists. This works out well for several reasons, but of-course it all depends on your setup.

Comment: You could also make your logic recursive so that if the "random" userID you get doesn't exist, then just run the process again. That may still be faster than trying to use the SQL built-in RAND() function.

Comment: What is the user selection criteria?

Comment: @Wain no specific criteria. It can be anyone in my Users table.

Comment: So can you keep a count of users separately and then simply skip to a point and pull 100 from there?

Comment: @Wain I guess that is a solution that could work. What if a criteria was: The updated date is within the last 7 days? Any way I could do that?

Comment: Yes, you can add that as a clause on the query

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so since you can only hunt through 1000 at a time, here is my solution for returning a random number of user objects. Your class names will be different..

```
-(IBAction)findAllUsers:(id)sender{

    //Random int between 1-1000
    int randomInt = arc4random() % 1000;

    NSMutableArray *allObjects = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSUInteger limit = randomInt;

    NSLog(@"Random User Count: %lu",(unsigned long)limit);

   //Keep going to the end of the objects
    __block NSUInteger skip = 0;

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"YourMainClass"];
    [query selectKeys:@[@"UserId"]];
    [query setLimit: limit];
    [query setSkip: skip];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        // The find succeeded. Add the returned objects to allObjects

        NSLog(@"Found %lu users", (unsigned long)objects.count);
        [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:objects];
        if (objects.count == limit) {

            skip += limit;
            [query setSkip: skip];

            [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                // Keep going until no objects left to find
                if (!error) {
                    [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:objects];
                }
                else{
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
                }

            }];
            }
        }];

    }
```